# Apostrophe pageBeforeSend : extended data is lost after editing widget

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm currently discovering Apostrophe and try to create a widget

I woulkd like to append external data to the data comming from mongo fields
As stated in the tutorials, i use `pageBeforeSend` (and 'super' pattern)

It works. My exernal datas are available in the nunjucks (through a `apos.area`) and i can use it !

But, if i edit my widget to modifiy somme 'mongo' fields, when back, the `pageBeforeSend` is not called and i do not have my external datas. If then refreshing the whole page, it will all be coming back up again.

my question : Is the `pageBeforeSend` the good approach to append external datas and how to force a widget to call pageBeforeSend (or whatever) when it exits its editing mode so that the external datas can be again available ?

my code : (the `data.my_extended` will be an array of objects at the end)

```
construct: function(self, options) {
    let superPageBeforeSend = self.pageBeforeSend;
    self.pageBeforeSend = function(req) {
        req.data.my_extended = 'some extra information not in fields';
        return superPageBeforeSend(req, function() {
          req.data.my_extended = 'some extra information for testing';
        });
    };
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want a widget to do a custom thing every time it loads you can override the `load` method instead.

This SO question has the relevant code snippet

[How-to access widget data in helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727029/how-to-access-widget-data-in-helper/47744232#47744232)

Comment: seems the right thing to do !! Thanks !! Btw, i also need to access a field of my widget as my extended_data depends on one of them. I'll look if it is available at that level (so many things to learn)

Comment: the contents of each widget should be in the array of objects called `widgets` that is in the load method

Answer (score 0):

I just found the `sanitize()` method to override

It does partially the job by being able to append my extended_data again