# How do i sort the pieces in my widget?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have the following problem,

I created a widget, that has the main function to show me all of my news-pieces. The news-piece has a field named "priority" which can be an integer that ranges from 0 to 100.

The main thing i want to do is to sort by "priority".

The following HTML-Code is my **news-widgets/views/widget.html**

```
{% for piece in data.widget._pieces %}
<div class="commercial_widget_wrapper">
    <a href="{{ piece.detaillink }}">
        <div class="commercial_widget_inner row">
            <div class="commercial_widget_thumbnail">
                {% set image = apos.images.first(piece.thumbnail) %}
                {% if image %}
                <img class="bild" src="{{ apos.attachments.url(image, { size: 'full' }) }}"/>
                {% endif %}
                {% if image == null %}
                <div class="bild">
                {{apos.area(piece, 'thumbnail', {edit:false, size: 'full'})}}
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="commercial_widget_label">
                <b>{{piece.title}}</b><br>
                {{piece.text}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I added the widget in the **show.html** of a page with

```
{{apos.singleton(data.page, 'news', 'news', {})}}
```

My Question is, how and where can i sort my results? I tried to find something with the help of [apostrophe-cursors](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/cursors.html) but the docs lack a good example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This SO question illustrates where you can interact with each widget's data before it makes it to your template

[How-to access widget data in helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727029/how-to-access-widget-data-in-helper/47744232)

By hooking into the `load` method of your widget you will have access to all the associated pieces. You can then use something like lodash's `sortBy` to reorder the array based on a property within each item.

Comment: That's the wrong answer (or at least very incomplete) - the OP wanted to know how to sort pieces within a widget, you solution only allows the sorting of the widgets (and if, for example, you have a list of files on your page there will be only one widget).